# How to convert diff output to HTML in Java?

Tags: java, diff

Are there any libraries (available in Maven Central) that can convert `diff` output to HTML? Or, maybe even better, to compare two texts and produce an HTML output of their difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this repository to your `pom.xml`:

```
<repository>
  <id>google-diff-patch-match</id>
  <name>google-diff-patch-match</name>
  <url>https://google-diff-match-patch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maven/</url>
</repository>
```

Comment: I found google-diff-patch-match. But how to generate html report? I can't find html related code.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how to make [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) available to my project.

I finally got it working by adding the following lines to my pom.xml:

```
<project.. >
  ..
  <repositories>
    ..
    <repository>
      <id>google-diff-patch-match</id>
      <name>google-diff-patch-match</name>
      <url>https://google-diff-match-patch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/maven/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  ..
  <dependencies>
    ..
    <dependency>
      <groupId>diff_match_patch</groupId>
      <artifactId>diff_match_patch</artifactId>
      <version>current</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the demo's of [google-diff-match-patch](http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) and see if it fits for you.

Comment: It's not in Maven Central, as far as I understand :(

Comment: @yegor256 seems like it isn't. you can however deploy in your company repo